# C++ access protected data in Super Class

Tags: c++, inheritance

hello guys can anyone help me :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    int a;

protected:
    int b;
    void set_value(int y, int u, int i)
    {
        a = y;
        b = u;
        c = i;
    }

public:
    int c;
};

class B : private A
{
public:
    A::set_value;       //Compilation Error !
    A::b;               //Compilation Error !
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.set_value(1,1,1);   //Compilation Error !
    cout<<b.b;            //Compilation Error !
}
```

How i Could Make protected member in super class can accessed directly (with out get() or set()) in main function using subclass

Comment: Which compiler? What is the error? On gcc/godbolt I only get a deprecated warning.

Comment: Gcc warns, but clang raises an error.

Comment: You can't... it's protected... that's the whole point... you can only re-expose it as public, which goes against the intentions of the base class's author. There's a design smell in your question.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings perhaps this is for testing? Definitely better than `#define private public` though.

Comment: @florestan Testing what? A bad design? :P

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) (emphasis mine)

> Using-declaration introduces a member of a base class into the derived class definition, such as to **expose a protected member of base as public member of derived**.

So the solution is to write the class as follows:

```
class B : private A
{
public:
    using A::set_value;       
    using A::b;               
};
```

Full example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fKzcv3).

It seems the access declarations were deprecated in C++98 and finally [removed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1144) in C++11.

Comment: fwiw, in godbolt you can "Add new -> execution only" to get https://godbolt.org/z/q8Yxn4. Sometimes the output is more convincing than just seeing no compiler errors

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

first when i use Clang++ it shows me error when i compile,
When I use G++ compiler version 9.3.0 it works with me correctly
Thanks Guys.